# Docker rm unable to remove all containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to remove all stopped containers to free up some space on an AWS Ubuntu server that I am using. Docker documentation says to use `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)` : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/#remove-all-stopped-containers

However, I am getting the error below:

```
"docker rm" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rm --help'.

Usage:  docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Remove one or more containers
```

Any suggestions?

Adding sudo in front doesn't help. I am able to remove individual containers using `docker rm 343e43ac4e86`, but I don't want to spend a lot of time trying to figure out which containers are from older releases and removing them one by one.

Comment: What shell are you using to run the command? I bet this is the problem with command substitution

Comment: Using MobaXterm to SSH into the server

Comment: I mean shell on remote server. Is it bash?

Comment: Yes, it is bash

Comment: What does `echo $(docker ps -a -q)` output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could also try `docker ps -aq | xargs docker rm` if the substitution doesn't work out.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I was then able to run `docker image prune` to clean up all the dangling images and leftover containers.

Answer (score 0):

Please use these command in your terminal:

```
   docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
   docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
   docker network prune -f
   docker rmi -f $(docker images --filter dangling=true -qa)
   docker volume rm $(docker volume ls --filter dangling=true -q)
```